# Condition to check if value is present or not

Tags: javascript, typescript

Fruits will contain only one value.
I need to check if "banana" is present or not in Fruits. If "Banana" is present, it should return true ,otherwise return false.

```
// Array Example : (If fruits contains many values)
        var fruits = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "mango"]; 
        bool n = fruits.includes("banana");
    
 // For my case:(If fruits contain single value)
        var fruits = ["banana"]; 
        bool n = fruits.includes("banana");
```

Is there any other way to check this condition when fruits contain only 1 value?

Comment: You can use the same method for that  Why you are looking for another way? any specific reason?

Comment: to check when fruits contain a single value u can do this way fruits.length == 1

Comment: to check if fruits contains many values fruits.length > 1

Comment: If the array always has one element, perhaps you should have just a value instead of an array? But otherwise, assuming one single element, `fruits[0] === 'banana'` would check if that element is "banana".

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use var for declaring variables. Instead use let or const.

Your solution is perfectly fine if you want only check if element exists in array.

For more complex searching you can try:

- array.filter() [MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- array.find() [MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is perfect for the case where you know that fruits contain much value.
But if you know that fruits only contains a single value, then you can use like this:
your case

```
        var fruits = ["banana"]; 
        var n = fruits.includes("banana");
```

solution

```
        let [fruits] = ["banana"];
```

this will give you the value as banana.

Comment: `let [fruits] = ["banana"];` assigns the first value in the array to `fruits`, regardless of if it is "banana", so I'm not sure how that works to give "true" if banana is in the array.

Comment: then you can check the fruits === "banana"

Comment: Why is the two steps of `let [fruits] = ["banana"]; let n = fruits === 'banana'` an improvement over `.includes`?

Answer (score 0):

In your example fruits.includes("banana") is already either "true" or "false", depending on the search-term and the array content you use.
In modern Javascript, if you want to save lines of code and make less use of variables, you could simply depend it by writing:

```
fruits.includes("banana") && console.log("Yes, that's true")
```

or more general

YourArray.includes("YourSearchTerm") && YourDesiredFunctionOrResult